# Paypal Recurrent payments - invalid token

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm trying to integrate a website with express checkout and recurrent payments. The express checkout works fine. That is, we redirect to paypal, then back to our site where the payment is confirmed and everything works like a charm.

But when trying to integrate the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile I get a response with the "Invalid Token" error (code 11502). I've seen many posts talking about the same problem but none of the replies helped me. I tried everything. I read the docs and the forum but nothing worked.

Please, if someone could help me I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I've seen similar to this is that recurring payments require the account you are using to collect payments must have the recurring payments feature enabled.

You may want to create a developer account in the PayPal sandbox to test with and see if it works there. If it does work, the issue is with the account type or features that are assigned to the real account.

If that's not it, please try to add more details.